# Swapped printer, no USB in Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, usb, printer

I have a bunch of HP P2055dn printers. 
One of them had to be replaced, so I disconnected it,
removed the printer from the printer list and connected a new one. 
The problem is that the system does not see a USB device plugged in;
there is no change in Device Manager, like nothing was connected. 
The printer is the same model as the previous one. 
I tried 3 other (working) printers,
I tried 3 other (working) USB cables and of course I tried every port in PC. 
Still – no USB device detected. 
I thought someone disabled new device detection,
but when I uninstalled the keyboard and connected it again,
it successfully did everything and is working as it should.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Does the PC detect a USB device that is not a printer?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't detect anything. No change in device manager, nothing.

Comment: I would guess a hardware problem.

Comment: Have you run `Scan for hardware changes` from the **Device Manager** toolbar?

Comment: Also set view to `Show hidden devices` and `Show devices by connectioin`. Delete the `USB Controller`. Screen will probably go black and then everything gets re-detected.

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't help. It looks like there was to much dust inside, when I cleaned the PC it worked.